# What is the reason for naming Ctrl + D or Ctrl + L to access address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Google Chrome has <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to access address bar.

Is there a specific reason for choosing these names/characters to represent the function?

Comment: Don't know the exact reason, for me it was always (don't forget that we have ctrl+b for bold in text editors, so no (B)ookmark) `add (D)estination`, and `change (L)ocation` :)

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: I was going to say the same as @Zina, I hadn't made the leap to D meaning destination though.

Comment: Thank you, English is not my native language and this makes it much more easier to remember.